# Problems building simple traffic light circuit on a breadboard

Tags: schematics, breadboard

I'm new to breadboarding and am trying to take this simple traffic light circuit and build it on a breadboard.

I'm trying to figure out where I went wrong but can't find the error. How can I fix this?

[Tinkercad Link](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/99jfYxMGarV-copy-of-traffic-light/editel?sharecode=fGhxOS6Z6JjGPGeiIrnmFrDT9R6ClhwxyIipq8Wenx4)

[image]

[image]

Comment: The output from your 555 does not appear to be going anywhere.  Also, your diodes are backwards.

Comment: Your jumper to pin 14 on the 4017 does not connect to the end point of the jumpers from pin 3 of the 555.  AFAIK Tinkercad should be able to give you a schematic -- look at what it's spitting out and compare it to the schematic you're trying to duplicate, see if you can spot the error.

Comment: You appear to have a dead short between power and ground, where the big electrolytic capacitor is.

Comment: I've made these changes. The red LED now lights up, however the green and yellow do not

Comment: Looking at the schematic, what are you trying to have the lights do?  The red LED is connected to CARRY OUT, which is high for count 0-4 and low 5-9.  The R-C on your RESET pin gives you a brief pulse when power is applied, then drops to zero.  But then it looks like you have red by itself for the first three pulses, then yellow turns on for a pulse, red and yellow turn off next pulse, green stays on for three pulses, and then yellow turns on again.  Can you verify that the 555 is oscillating properly?